# How can I detect facial elements using OpenCV on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv

I'm using OpenCV to develop an iPhone application, and I'm using it to detect faces. Rather than detect the face as a whole, I would like to detect each of the smaller facial features (eyes, nose, ears, lips, etc.).

How can I do this using OpenCV?

Comment: Could you should some of your relevant code please.

Comment: See the accepted answer here for a pretty good breakdown of using OpenCV to detect facial features: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10968479/19679